# Leading spaces while trying to print a number in Ada

Tags: ada

I wrote a program which accepts an integer as input and prints the integer as output in Ada. When i run the program, it's printing the number but there are several leading white spaces. Does anybody know why it's happening? Here's the code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Float_Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada;

procedure Solution is

  Int:   Integer;
begin

 Integer_Text_IO.Get (Int);
 Integer_Text_IO.Put (Int);

end Solution;
```

[image: Terminal output]

Comment: don't you mean _leading_ white spaces?

Comment: @egilhh i have added the output screenshot and it's trailing whitespaces. :)

Comment: Well, it certainly looks like leading white spaces, as mandated by the standard: "If the resulting sequence of characters to be output has fewer than Width characters, then leading spaces are first output to make up the difference." [RM A.10.8(13)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html). If you want a different behaviour, specify width, like this: Integer_Text_IO.Put (Int, Width => 1);

Comment: @egilhh thanks for the fast reply and it worked. I think you should add this as an answer so that people looking for it can find this easily.

Comment: “leading space” means _before_ the visible characters; “trailing space” means _after_. People will be able to find this more easily if you correct this throughout the question (especially the title).

Comment: _before_ means _left_ side and _after_ means _right_ side. I think this was a perspective confusion. Left of something can be thought as after of something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Leading* white spaces are mandated by the standard: "If the resulting sequence of characters to be output has fewer than Width characters, then leading spaces are first output to make up the difference." [RM A.10.8(13)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html).

If you want a different behaviour, specify width, like this:
`Integer_Text_IO.Put (Int, Width => 1);`

Answer (score 0):

The definition for the Put procedure has the width parameter as being on type Field. Its definition is...

```
subtype Field is Integer range 0 .. implementation-defined;
```

I'd recommend putting a field width of 0, which I think stands out more than 1.

Alternatively you could just set the default field width...

```
Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Default_Width = 0;
```

in the startup section of your program, which will ensure that all output from this package has no leading spaces.

Comment: is there a way to set the default width to 0 only once or for each program should i do that?

Comment: You can create a procedure in a package that performs initialisations (being careful with elaboration order), and then call that from just inside the main program.

Another way is very clunky - have it in a package body initialisation. As a package body can't be present unless there is a need for it, a dedicated package for this purpose would have to declare a useless subprogram just so the package body would be required.